# DS Cartridge That Freezes

Tags: nintendo-ds

I have 2 DS cartridges that freeze on all DS/DSi's that I have tried. I have tried cleaning them with alcohol with no change. Is there any way to fix them?

Comment: I don't suppose when the game freezes, you get Vuvuzela's blared at you? -> http://www.wired.com/gamelife/2010/12/michael-jackson-vuvuzela/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is one of them Age of Kings?

That DS game has a save game bug that fries the cartridge, making it unusable.

Comment: Yes, it is. Does the manufacturer offer replacement at all, or is it garbage?

Answer (score 2):

Try and get a refund at the store, if that doesn't work, contact Nintendo.